# PHP - matching to all exist phrases in text - preg_replace

Tags: php

Here is my text:

```
$msg_text = '[quote]TEXT[/quote]';
```

and my preg_replace:

```
$msg_text = preg_replace('#\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]#is', '"$1"'."\r\n", $msg_text);
```

And it works fine. But what when my text is looking like that:

```
$msg_text = '[quote]TEXT [quote]TEXT[/quote][/quote]';
```

?? My preg_replace doesn't work on this example. How I can replcace this text in all instances ?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `?` after `.*` which will remove the laziness of your pattern.

```
'#\[quote\](.*)\[\/quote\]#is'
```

**What is Laziness in Regex?**

Patterns like `.*` and `.+` normally **greedy**, which means they will try to match as long as they can. Putting an extra `?` after it we tell it to become **lazy**, so it will take only nearest / shortest match. So, if you remove that, it will work as it's normal way.

Note: Other use of `?` is to make the previous item optional, which is not the case here, because by using `*` you are making that part optional already.

Learn more from here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Won't removing the `?` make `[quote]foo[/quote]...[quote]bar[/quote]` -> `foo[/quote]...[quote]bar`?

Comment: @kingkero How? I don't get you! Can you pls clarify a bit more?

Comment: See [yours](https://regex101.com/r/pC7jJ4/1) and [OPs](https://regex101.com/r/pC7jJ4/2)

Comment: Yes, That's what it will match and that's what he is trying to replace.

Comment: No. OP is asking about nested tags (one inside the other). I posted an example with two tags after another

Comment: Yes, I see the nested tags. But I think he is trying to replace the whole thing inside the parent tag. Let's wait for OP's response here.